# How to fix type argument error with generic method inside non generic class?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, efcore.bulkextensions

I have a project called `Persistance` where I have installed Nuget Package called [EFCore.BulkExtensions](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions) for bulk insert.

I have another project called `Application` which defines the Interface representing the `DBset` as below :

**Application Project:**

```
public interface IDatabaseService
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employee {get;set;}
    
    public DbSet<Department> Department {get;set;}
    
    public void Save();
    
    public void Insert<T>(IEnumerable<T> lists);
    
    public int ExecuteSP(string procedureName,params object[] parameters);
}
```

**Persistance project :**

```
using EFCore.BulkExtensions;
public class MyDatabaseContext : DbContext,IDatabaseService
{
   private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
   public MyDatabaseContext(IConfiguration configuration)
   {
        _configuration = configuration;
         Database.EnsureCreated(); 
   }
   public DbSet<Employee> Employee {get;set;}
    
   public DbSet<Department> Department {get;set;}
   
   
   public void Save()
   {
        this.SaveChanges();
   }
   
   public void Insert<T>(IEnumerable<T> lists)
   {
      this.BulkInsert(lists);/error here
   }
}
```

> Error: type arguments for method
> DbContextBulkExtensions.BulkInsert(DbContext, IList) cannot be
> inferrred from the usage.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the `async` methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [The source-code of the `EFCore.BulkExtensions.DbContextBulkExtensions` is available on GitHub](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions/blob/30c18a1eadbddeb7082b1eb4511687db677db2f9/EFCore.BulkExtensions/DbContextBulkExtensions.cs#L25).

  - The `BulkInsert<T>` methods require entities to be passed in via `IList<T>` collections][1](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions/blob/30c18a1eadbddeb7082b1eb4511687db677db2f9/EFCore.BulkExtensions/DbContextBulkExtensions.cs#L25), and not as `IEnumerable<T>`.
  - Additionally, they also constrain `T` to `where T : class`, so add that constraint too.

So change this:

```
public void Insert<T>( IEnumerable<T> lists )
{
    this.BulkInsert(lists);/error here
}
```

to this:

```
public void Insert<T>( IList<T> entities )
    where T : class
{
    this.BulkInsert( entities: entities );
}
```

Comment: IList is not working either. It says type "T" must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter "T" in the generic type or method 'DBContextBulkExtensions.BulkInsert<T>(DbContext,IList<T>"

Comment: @Learning-Overthinker-Confused My mistake, I didn't see the `where T : class` constraint in `DbContextBulkExtensions.cs`. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me. Appreciate your help :)